Phragmen-Lindelof type argument to show entire function identically zero
I want to show that if an entire function $f$ satisfies the bound $|f(z)| \leq 1/|\operatorname{Im}(z)|$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then it must be identically zero. I know this sort of result is among the many generalizations of the maximum principle to unbounded regions, but I'm having some trouble wrapping up my argument.
I want to show that $f$ has a removable singularity at infinity. I know that if $f$ is bounded, then it must be identically zero. To this end, I want to show that some function I can construct out of $f$ is bounded and entire, hence constant by Liouville. How do I show this and conclude? Thank you.
